# SugarCRM Integration - Community edition -Rest vrs SOAP

Tags: rest, soap, sugarcrm

We have a setup where SugarCRM will be deployed/hosted on AWS Cloud and it has to be integrated with a Portal application and Mobile App. 
Considering the scenario, which SugarCRM APIs should be preferred for integration i.e SOAP OR REST and why?
Or should we use SOAP for portal and REST for mobile app integration?

Answer (score 0):

Use REST.  According to the SugarCRM support site, "SOAP support is deprecated as of 7.x and you should move integrations over to the new REST endpoint".